# Determining $\langle a,b,c\mid 6a+9b+6c=0, 8a+12b+4c=0\rangle^{\operatorname{ab}}.$

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups, group-presentation, combinatorial-group-theory

I have to find out what is this abelian group (in the form $\mathbb{Z}/m_1\mathbb{Z} \times  ... $). Its relations are:
$$6a+9b+6c=0$$
$$8a+12b+4c=0$$
with generator $a,b,c$.
My solution is: $$\mathbb{Z}/12\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}$$
But the first term should be a $14$ instead according to the book, Can someone help me and explain how to get there? I don't understand it.

My work:
I transform the system up there into:
$$6t+3u=0$$
$$8t+4u-4v=0$$
with $t=a+b+c$, $u=b$, $v=c$
Then, I transform it again in:
$$3x=0$$
$$4x-4\mathbb{Z}=0\longrightarrow 4(x-\mathbb{Z})=0$$
with $x=u+2t$, $v=\mathbb{Z}$
So the group is $$\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}$$
And $\mathbb{Z}_3\times \mathbb{Z}_4$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/12\mathbb{Z}$, so the group is:
$$\mathbb{Z}/12\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}$$

Can someone check that's right?

Comment: Presumably, you mean abelian group

Comment: Ho did you get $12$

Comment: 12 is correct..

Comment: Yes it's abelian. I got the twelve just by transforming the relations and getting new generators, until I had something of the form $zu_1=0$ So I know that corresponds to $Z/xZ$

Comment: @anon yes, that was a typo. I wrote what I've done.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I wrote my work, is anything wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You're correct.

You are given that the group is abelian. Multiplicatively, the group is given by the presentation

$$\langle a,b,c\mid a^6b^9c^6, a^8b^{12}c^4\rangle^{\operatorname{ab}}. \tag{$P$}$$

What you have done is introduce $t=abc, u=b, v=c$ to $(P)$ via Tietze transformations to get the presentation

$$\langle a,b,c\mid a^6b^9c^6, a^8b^{12}c^4\rangle^{\operatorname{ab}}=\langle t,u,v\mid t^6u^3, t^8u^4v^{-4}\rangle^{\operatorname{ab}}.$$

Your next step is a bit hazy about its notation, so I shall correct you a little here.

You used other Tietze transformations to introduce $x=ut^2$, so that $x^3=(ut^2)^3=1$, and $z=v$, so that $(ut^2)^4v=x^4z^{-4}$, then introducing $y=xz^{-1}$, which means $(P)$ is isomorphic to

$$\langle x, y, z\mid x^3, y^4\rangle^{\operatorname{ab}} $$

which defines the group $\Bbb Z_3\times\Bbb Z_4\times\Bbb Z\cong \Bbb Z_{12}\times\Bbb Z$.